# PL/SQL and Oracle Forms Builder

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

So I need to put this project together for school, but I'm ONLY allowed to use oracle forms builder.

I'm trying to do a simple query and assign values to the form objects based on what I get from the query, but my form items are coming up as undeclared. Does anyone know how I can modify form attributes like this? This user interface on this program is awful, so doing it through the wizards is something I'd really like to avoid if I can just make things happen in PL/SQL.

Here's what I have:
[image]
Still trying to find a working solution.

I've modified my code a bit:

```
DECLARE
    pmrn patient.p_mrn%TYPE;
    var_ptuple patient%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    pmrn := NAME_IN('MRN_FIELD');
    SELECT * INTO var_ptuple from patient WHERE patient.p_mrn = pmrn;
    :PATIENT_BLOCK.FNAME := var_ptuple.p_fname;
    :PATIENT_BLOCK.LNAME := var_ptuple.p_lname;
END;
```

Using the where on the data block doesn't really suit these purposes because I would like to retrieve the data based on the user input. Ie. the user needs to input the correct user ID to see their records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form items can be referred to as bind variables in Forms PL/SQL, e.g.

```
pmrn := :PATIENT_BLOCK.MRN_FIELD;
:PATIENT_BLOCK.FNAME := var_ptuple.p_fname;
```

etc.

Be aware, however, that you most probably don't need to write all this code. Just set the block source to be the table and execute a query on it - Forms will take care of loading the records for you.

Comment: So could I write a query like this?

    select p_fname, plname from patient where patient.p_mrn =          :PATIENT_BLOCK.MRN_FIELD

I'm trying to disallow access to records where the user doesn't have the necessary info (like an ID number and a password or something). 

It seems like the GUI based setup doesn't offer these kinds of functionalities.

Comment: The GUI is just what you use to do the layout. The functionality of Forms is powerful and unleashed by object properties. Sometimes you do have to write some PL/SQL but for this sort of thing it's not necessary. For example, if you want to make sure the user only sees certain records, you can put a predicate in the `DEFAULT_WHERE` property on the block (you can even set this programmatically if the clause should be dynamic).

Comment: I've changed my code a bit but I'm still unclear as to how to access form objects and put data into them and/or retrieve data from them. If I can do that, I should be OK for this project. The syntax is correct for what you have suggested, but running the form it doesn't do what I expect it to do. It doesn't do anything, to be specific.

I would like the user to be able to input their ID into 'MRN_FIELD', take the value in the form, use it for a DB query, and take the info from the records and put it into the form for output.

Comment: Nevermind it worked! Whatever it was didn't like that I was using an ENTER KEY PRESSED trigger. I just tied it to a button and it worked like a charm. Mucho thanks!

Comment: Yep, avoid the "key" triggers - they're only useful when you need things to happen specific to certain keyboard keys. It's better to hang triggers off the generic events, such as "WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE" (to run something when the form is first opened) or "WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED" (to run something when a button is pressed - regardless of *how* it was pressed, e.g. mouse or keyboard)

Comment: Another thing you can do is put a "POST-CHANGE" trigger on the `MRN_FIELD` item which does something whenever the user puts an ID into it (and then tabs out of the field)

Comment: Thanks Jeffery! You've been a huge help. I dunno how kosher it is for me to advertise another question, but I think you might be able to help me with this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891873/oracle-forms-builder-pl-sql-access-a-column-that-is-dervied-from-other-columns?noredirect=1#comment26132220_17891873