# oracle forms builder pl/sql - access a column that is dervied from other columns

Tags: database, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a view in my database that has a bunch of fields derived from other information in the database, this is how the view is defined:

```
create view patient_account_view AS 
  select patient.p_mrn,
         p_fname,
         p_lname,
         ammount_paid,
         quantity*item_cost + repeats*item_cost  "ammount_owing", 
         (quantity*item_cost + repeats*item_cost) - ammount_paid "balance"
    from patient_account,
         patient,
         diagnosis,
         prescribed_treatment,
         items_used,
         item,
         perscription
    where patient.p_mrn = diagnosis.p_mrn AND
          patient_account.p_mrn = patient.p_mrn AND
          diagnosis.prescribed_treatment_id = prescribed_treatment.prescribed_treatment_id AND 
          prescribed_treatment.prescribed_treatment_id = perscription.prescribed_treatment_id AND
          items_used.ptreatment_id = prescribed_treatment.prescribed_treatment_id AND
          items_used.item_number = item.item_number;
```

I would like to use pl/sql to access the information in the view to stick it into a form, but I'm getting a 'bad bind variable' error. How do I access this kind of attribute without having to recalculate the information stored there?

Here is the plsql that is problematic:

```
DECLARE
    pmrn patient.p_mrn%TYPE;
    var_ptuple patient%ROWTYPE;
    var_accttuple patient_account%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    pmrn := :PATIENT_BLOCK.MRN_FIELD;
    SELECT * INTO var_ptuple from patient WHERE patient.p_mrn = pmrn;
    SELECT * INTO var_accttuple from patient_account_view WHERE patient_account_view.p_mrn = pmrn;
    :PATIENT_BLOCK.FNAME := var_ptuple.p_fname;
    :PATIENT_BLOCK.LNAME := var_ptuple.p_lname;
    :PATIENT_BLOCK.BALACNCE_OWING := var_accttuple.balance;
END;
```

Comment: What is `:PATIENT_BLOCK`?

Comment: It's a forms builder data block. So :PATIENT_BLOCK.MRN_FIELD is a text field on my oracle form, but that's not the problematic line the problematic line is this: ":PATIENT_BLOCK.BALACNCE_OWING := var_accttuple.balance;"

Comment: Could it be that the field on your form is named `BALANCE_OWING` rather than `BALACNCE_OWING` as you have it in the code?  I only ask because the word "balance" appears to be spelled correctly elsewhere and might have been a typo here...

Comment: derp derp derp.. yup that was it.. also worth noting, that it didn't like the attribute name balance for the derived attribute.. i had to enclose it in quotes like so:

var_accttuple."balance";

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using double-quotes for identifiers, e.g. `"balance"` except in very specific circumstances - makes things easier overall.

Comment: At the moment your code executes two separate queries to basically just get data for one patient. It would be more efficient to get it in one query - e.g. by adding the other data required for `var_ptuple` into the view, so that you just need to query the view.

Comment: As @JeffreyKemp noted, the reason you had to put double-quotes around it in the PL/SQL statement is because you did so in the SELECT statement.  Double-quoted identifiers are case-sensitive and IMO are more bother than they're worth.  If you change the SELECT statement line defining 'balance' to `(quantity*item_cost + repeats*item_cost) - ammount_paid as balance` it will then be case-insensitive and you can forget about double-quoting it from then on.  (The `as` isn't really required but I always put it in). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of your view `patient_account_view` do not match exactly the columns of the table `patient_account`, but in your code you have:

```
var_accttuple patient_account%ROWTYPE;
```

which means when you run this:

```
SELECT * INTO var_accttuple from patient_account_view ...
```

You haven't specified which columns get mapped to which record attributes, so Oracle requires that the column list matches exactly.

In this case, I'd expect you probably want to change the definition of the variable, e.g.

```
var_accttuple patient_account_view%ROWTYPE;
```

**Side note**

Since you're only using one attribute from the view, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
SELECT balance INTO :PATIENT_BLOCK.BALACNCE_OWING
from patient_account_view WHERE patient_account_view.p_mrn = pmrn;
```

and you no longer need `var_accttuple`.